# inner classes and variables in WCF service class

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got class in WCF. Inside this class - there are 2 classes, 1 interface and several variables. It adds as service reference without errors.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class XmlService
{
    private string filename;
    private XmlTextReader xmlreader;
    List<IWeather> returner=new List<IWeather>();
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoWork()
    {
     // Add your operation implementation here
     return;
    }

    interface IWeather
    {
      string GetCondition { get; set; }
      DateTime GetDate { get; set; }
     }

     public class Current_Weather:IWeather
     {
        private string condition, humidity, wind_condition;
        private int temp_f, temp_c;
        private DateTime day;
        public string GetCondition
        {
            get { return condition; }
            set { condition = value; }
        }
        public string GetHumidity
        {
            get { return humidity; }
            set { humidity = value; }
        }
        public string GetWindCondition
        {
            get { return wind_condition; }
            set { wind_condition = value; }
        }
        public int TEMP_F
        {
             get { return temp_f; }
             set { temp_f = value; }
        }
        public int TEMP_C
        {
            get { return temp_c; }
            set { temp_c = value; }
        }
        public DateTime GetDate
        {
        get { return day; }
        set { day = value; }
        }
    }
    public class Forecast_Weather:IWeather
    {
        public string condition;
        public int lowT, highT;
        public DateTime day;
        public string GetCondition
        {
            get { return condition; }
            set { condition = value; }
        }
        public int GetLowT
        {
            get { return lowT; }
            set { lowT = value; }
        }
        public int HighT
        {
            get { return highT; }
            set { highT = value; }
        }
        public DateTime GetDate
        {
            get { return day; }
            set { day = value; }
        }
    }


}
```

Should I add contracts to variables,interface IWeather, for inner classes and its methods and variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them serialzied and visible on the client they need to be marked with contract attributes.

Internal classes aren't really a good practice, instead put all your operations in one interface marked up as a service contract, then all your data contracts in their own class libraries so you can reference that assemply frmo your client.  This facilitates writing your own proxies and other good habits.

Comment: I've added it to my silverlight project as silverlight-enabled wcf service and it hasn't generated file with interface declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your internal classes will not be exposed to callers of your service, since your service doesn't use them either as parameters or as return values.